# Chromium won't open web page properly when launched from CLI

Tags: raspbian, chromium

I am running raspbian on a Pi4 in desktop mode. Everything is up to date (apt update/upgrade).

I want to open a web page from the command line. I have tried "chromium-browser http://localhost/index.html" but am getting weird results. Chrome starts and after a while puts up the dialogue box to say that the page is unresponsive and offering Wait or Exit Page options. Clicking on Exit Page brings up the "Aw, snap" page with error code 5 and the option to Reload. Clicking on Reload results in the page being loaded fine.

If I launch Chrome from the menu, I can load this page first time with no problem. If I "curl" this page, I can see that the page is available. I have cleared all cookies and cached data.

Why is Chrome doing this and how can I get it to open the page first time?

Comment: I noticed the same issue. Manually open a second tab after starting from CLI works. It seems that the network is not ready inside chromium for the first seconds or something like this. Did you already found a solution?